# Find an item on sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, 2013

When i use the "Find an item" option on a list through sharepoint 2013.

Result is Your search returned no results.

Do i need to do any specific setup?

Comment: I haven't seen or worked with SharePoint 2013, but I'd say its a good bet your Search Crawler/indexer hasn't run yet. Check your search service.

Comment: This is an known issue of SharePoint 2013. We should wait for a update or fix.

Comment: Same issue here with SharePoint 2013 SP1. "find an item" does not search trough all field, so the results are often unsatisfying... Still seeking for the cause of this issue... :-/